# does bootstrap apply special font application rules across elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I added a bootstrap.css reference to an existing site.  Then I changed the font-family and font-size at the body level to Roboto Google Web Font.  The font application looked good.

However, the bootstrap reference broke some other functionality in the site so I removed the bootstrap reference.  However, when I did this, the font application did not look as good.  The font style did not get applied to the textbox.  when I experimented with different font sizes for the textbox, the overall look was not as good as when the site had the bootstrap.css reference.

Based on my experience, I'm assuming that the bootstrap refs have some sort of intelligence to optimize the application of a font across a site.  Is this correct?  If so then can I somehow apply this functionality of Bootstrap without adding the full bootstrap reference?  Or is there some other specialized 3rd-party libs that I can add to my website that will do this without the additional bootstrap overhead and potential conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

textarea, and inputs don't inherit the font and some other css properties...So you should do this:

```
textarea, input {
  font-family: whichever-you-want;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: But when the bootstrap references were added to my website, I simply made 2 css updates:  body {font-size:1.2em;font-family:roboto } and these changes were applied to all elements including inputs.  This led me to think that bootstrap uses some type of optimizer/inference engine to apply font updates across website elements.